# Is there a way to interpolate all ${project.version} variables in a Maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, jgitver, flatten-maven-plugin

I need to replace all occurrences of `${project.version}` with the real value in a pom.xml.

I can do that with the `maven-flatten-plugin`, but that will rewrite the whole pom.xml instead of just replacing the `project.version` only.

As I want to use the `jgitver-maven-plugin` I can't use the `resolveCiFriendliesOnly` mode of the flatten plugin.

Is there an easy way to replace only one variable in the whole pom.xml? Is there another (hidden) option in the flatten plugin to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the content of a variable or the actual version of the POM like `<version>1</version>`  to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven release plugin, specifically the update-versions goal.

ex:
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

There is something close to what you want to achieve, but may be good enough.
However this will resolve all variables in POM sections of your choice.

I used `resolveCiFriendliesOnly`, as it's the only mode that kind of preserves the original POM.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
                    <pomElements>
                        <dependencyManagement>resolve</dependencyManagement>
                        <!-- add more sections to resolve -->
                    </pomElements>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now you can add more sections under `<pomElements>` where you want variables resolved.
As a side-effect of `resolveCiFriendliesOnly`, variables `${revision}`, `${sha1}` and `${changelist}` will be resolved in the whole POM file.

Keep in mind that `flatten-maven-plugin` will still rewrite your POM, i.e. you may get sections reordered, lose comments, indentation, etc.

Here's a list of sections you can configure:
https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/apidocs/org/codehaus/mojo/flatten/FlattenDescriptor.html

If `resolveCiFriendliesOnly` still messes up your POM, you can remove `flattenMode`, but then it will go wild and you must add nearly all possible sections to `<pomElements>` with `keep` option, e.g.

```
<pomElements>
    <dependencyManagement>resolve</dependencyManagement>
    <!-- keep everything else -->
    <parent>keep</parent>
    <build>keep</build>
    <distributionManagement>keep</distributionManagement>
    <repositories>keep</repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>keep</pluginRepositories>
    <profiles>keep</profiles>
    ...
</pomElements>
```